# Overhead of ASM-function-call in go

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, go

I currently play around with go, it's assembly, performance of floating point operations (`float32`) and optimizations in the nano-seconds-scale. I was a bit confused by the overhead of a simple function call:

```
func BenchmarkEmpty(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    }
}
func BenchmarkNop(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        doNop()
    }
}
```

The implementation of doNop:

```
TEXT ·doNop(SB),0,$0-0
    RET
```

The result (`go test -bench .`):

```
BenchmarkEmpty        2000000000               0.30 ns/op
BenchmarkNop  2000000000               1.73 ns/op
```

Im not used to assembly and/ or the internals of go. It is possible fo the go compiler/ linker to inline a function defined in assembly? Can I give the linker a hint somehow? For some simple functions like 'add two R3-vectors' this eats up all possible performance gain.

(go 1.4.2, amd64)

Comment: Are you sure Go isn't just optimizing away the loop in BenchmarkEmpty()?  If it does, comparing BenchmarkEmpty with BenchmarkNop isn't much of a comparison.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've taken a look into the disassembly and the loop is still there. A generic implementation of doNop (`func doNopGeneric(){}`) is optimized away btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly functions are not inlined. Here are 3 things you could try:

1. Move your loop into assembly. For example with this function:

   ```
   func Sum(xs []int64) int64
   ```

   You can do this:

   ```
   #include "textflag.h"

   TEXT ·Sum(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-24
       MOVQ  xs+0(FP),DI
       MOVQ  xs+8(FP),SI
       MOVQ  $0,CX
       MOVQ  $0,AX

   L1: CMPQ  AX,SI           // i < len(xs)
       JGE   Z1
       LEAQ  (DI)(AX*8),BX   // BX = &xs[i]
       MOVQ  (BX),BX         // BX = *BX
       ADDQ  BX,CX           // CX += BX
       INCQ  AX              // i++
       JMP   L1

   Z1: MOVQ  CX,ret+24(FP)
       RET
   ```

   If you look in the standard libraries you will see examples of this.
2. Write some of your code in c, leverage the support it has for intrinsics or inline assembly, and use cgo to call it from go.
3. Use gccgo to do the same thing as #2, except you can do it directly:

   ```
   //extern open
   func c_open(name *byte, mode int, perm int) int
   ```

   https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo#Function_names

Comment: I was hoping to inline some primitive functions in ASM and still building my algorithm in go. But a negative answer is still an answer ;)